# How to get all dependency jars for deployment

Tags: maven

I am using one Apache open source project and its pre-built binary contains all the target jars and the corresponding dependency jars for deployment.

But when I build from source like `mvn clean install`, how could I also get the necessary dependency jars for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two options:

1. Build a fat jar: the maven output jar will contain ll necessary classes taken from its dependencies. To accomplish this task you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` maven plugin. You can read a good tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/).
2. Configure maven to copy all needed jar in a specific folder. To accomplish this task you can use the `maven-dependency-plugin` maven plugin. You will find a good tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven).